# Android Studio on Google Cloud Platform (Windows): Error can't run on a VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, android

My goal is to use Android Studio with the Test Function on a Google Cloud VM (Windows), so that I can always use it remote.

My Problem is, that when I start the emulation of a Smartphone in Android Studio, I get the Error that I can`t run the emulation in a VM. I now that there is a trick to do this in VMBox, so that you fool the System that it is a physically machine and not a VM (you do some changes in the Registry).
Can someone tell me if there is a solution?

And it is not a Problem for me to set up a new VM if there is only a solution on an older Windows Version.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run virtual machines in a Google Cloud virtual machine itself, you must have [nested virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) enabled for that virtual machine instance.

Note that you can only use a Linux instance for this, and you will need to create a new instance. So you will need to install Android Studio on Linux.